# MS Word GUI status bar is huge for some documents

Tags: microsoft-word

This is standard size:

[image]

Some documents have enormous size:

[image]

This menu can hide the bottom bar AND ribbon

[image]

This Display settings is the same for both documents:

[image]

Microsoft® Word pro Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.14026.20202) 64bit

How can I get a small size back?

Comment: For purposes of searching online, the bottom bar is called the "status bar."

Comment: The translations are hell when you need to search. Thanks

Comment: If you open these specific documents on other computers, is this issue reproduced? Please go to chceck whether you enabled [Touch mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/turn-touch-mode-on-or-off-90e162b1-44f9-434f-bc2b-9321c989ea6e).